# Controlling slick slider with external links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using slick slider. I have created two div's. Here is details :)

```
<a href="#" class="Full_Left"></a>
<a href="#" class="Full_Right"></a>
```

This is the css for these two divs

```
.Full_Left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(34, 25, 165, 0.5);
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;

}

.Full_Left:hover {
  cursor: url(../images/right.svg), auto;
}

.Full_Right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(216, 33, 33, 0.5);
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.Full_Right:hover {
  cursor: url(../images/left.svg), auto;
}
```

as you can see now my div's are on full screen and I want to control the slider with the links I have created so that when user bring mouse on 50% he have right arrow and same for left side and all of the slider content will be below these two layers.

I am wondering this is possible with "Slick" or not ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i see no divs in your code

Comment: Why don't you style the slicks controls instead of creating new one?

Comment: Slip of fingers..!! I want to link with these anchors :)

Comment: Actually I am going to achive this look using CSS [link](http://mirkoborsche.com/2015-Bayerisches-Staatsballett-Colouring-Book)       I have achieved this thing except that I need to link slick slider with these anchors.

Comment: But what is the problem using the slicks controls? You can style them as you want

Comment: have you seen the link i have mentioned above ?

Comment: I want to divide full screen in to two portions and then that two portions will control the slider. This make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by my self. here is my working code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.Full_Right').click(function(e) {
        $('#Contrroll').slick('slickNext');
    });

    $('.Full_Left').click(function(e) {
        $('#Contrroll').slick('slickPrev');
    });
</script>
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar use case to this, though with a twist. Finding this question pointed me in the right direction, and my answer below does address controlling a Slick slider with external links.

I have a Slick slider in the right column set to `position: fixed` and a longer story in the right column that scrolls. Each of the slides in the slider corresponds to a section of the story, set apart by `<h3>` tags. I wanted a link next to each header that set the slideshow to the corresponding slide when clicked. To accomplish this, I added a button at the end of each section header:

```
<h3>Section Header <button data-slick-index="0" class="slide-to"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></h3>
```

The `data-slick-index` property (is it a property?) was set to the slick-index of the corresponding slide. Then just below my Slick init JS I placed the following:

```
$(".slide-to").bind("click", function() {
    var slidx = $(this).attr('data-slick-index');
    $('#slideshow').slick('slickGoTo', slidx); 
});
```

Works like a charmp*.

*That's a charm and a champ combined.*

Comment: given the fact that you use jQuery, why don't you just do: `$('#slideshow').slick('slickGoTo', $(this).data('slick-index'));`